# Animation cannot take place between different router views in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, animation, vue-router, vue-cli-3

**Summary**
I am looking for a solution to create an animation across two different router views in Vue. The problem I met is that when the browser change to another router view, it will re-render the page. So the animation will disappear when the browser re-render.

**The Animation** 
Basically, the app has two different pages, *homepage* and *aboutpage*. When the user clicks the blue menu button, a green navigation menu will slide from the left to right until covers the whole screen. This menu has two links: *about* and *home*. If the user clicks the *about*, a white overlay will move from the left and cover the whole screen, then it moves to the right and then disappears. The about page shows after it disappears.
Here is the codepen example that demostrate the animation effect I want to achieve (this demo did not use a router).
https://codepen.io/wl1664209734/pen/qBamXEL 
**Below is the code to recreate the animation in vue template in codepen**

```
  <template>
  <div class="wrap">
    <!--Transition Overlay -->
    <transition
      name="page-shift"
      enter-active-class="animate__animated animate__slideInLeft animate__faster"
      leave-active-class="animate__animated animate__slideOutRight animate__faster"
    >
      <div v-if="showOverlay" class="overlay"></div>
    </transition>

    <!--Navigation Menu -->
    <transition
      name="slide"
      enter-active-class="animate__animated animate__slideInLeft animate__faster"
      leave-active-class="animate__animated animate__slideOutLeft animate__faster"
    >
      <div v-if="menuOpen" class="navigation">
        <div
          class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
        >
          <div class="text-center">
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold text-light" @click="pageShiftToHome">
              HOME
            </h3>
            <h3 class="font-weight-bold text-light" @click="pageShiftToAbout">
              ABOUT
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>

    <!--NavBar -->
    <div class="navbar d-flex justify-content-end">
      <div
        @click="menuOpen = !menuOpen"
        class="nav-link font-weight-bold mt-3 btn btn-primary"
      >
        Menu
      </div>
    </div>

    <!--Home Page -->
    <div
      v-if="showHomePage"
      class="homepage d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
    >
      <h1 class="text-light">HOME</h1>
    </div>

    <!--About Page -->
    <div
      v-if="showAboutPage"
      class="aboutpage d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
    >
      <h1 class="text-light">ABOUT</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      menuOpen: false,
      showHomePage: true,
      showAboutPage: false,
      showOverlay: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    pageShiftToHome: function () {
      this.showOverlay = !this.showOverlay;

      const _this = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        _this.menuOpen = !_this.menuOpen;
        _this.showAboutPage = false;
        _this.showHomePage = true;
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function () {
        _this.showOverlay = !_this.showOverlay;
      }, 1000);
    },

    pageShiftToAbout: function () {
      this.showOverlay = !this.showOverlay;

      const _this = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        _this.menuOpen = !_this.menuOpen;
        _this.showHomePage = false;
        _this.showAboutPage = true;
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function () {
        _this.showOverlay = !_this.showOverlay;
      }, 1000);
    }
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Use preprocessors via the lang attribute! e.g. <style lang="scss"> -->
<style lang="scss">
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #292929;
}

.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #292929;

  .overlay {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
  }

  .navigation {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background: #3ecc28;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 111;

    h3 {
      cursor: pointer;
    }
  }

  .navbar {
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 333;
    .nav-link {
      color: #fff;
      cursor: pointer;
      border: 0;
    }
  }

  .homepage {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }

  .aboutpage {
    @extend .homepage;
  }
}
</style>
```

**Explanation of my code** 
Here is the codeSandbox link, I reproduce the problem in this sandbox, I think this will help people understand my problem better.
https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-page-shift-anime-yp1yf 
In this sandbox, I used a vue template. It includes one primary component: *App.vue*, and 5 other components: *Homepage.vue, Aboutpage.vue, Background.vue, Navbar.vue, Navigation.vue*. The *Background* contains *navbar* and *Navigation* to form the static elements for the app. Both *Homepage* and *Aboutpage* have *Background* and a unique header. *Homepage*'s header is HOME, *Aboutpage*'s header is ABOUT. Then, I configure the router in the main.js and put router-view tag in the *App.vue*. I also add the router-link to *Navigation.vue*. I add a click event (page-shift) to the router-link, this event is emitted to *Background.vue*. So when user click the link, it will invoke the pageShift method in the  *Background.vue*, cause the animation to happen.

[image: App stucture]

Here is the code for the important components

*Main.js

```
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import VueRouter from "vue-router";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "animate.css";

import Homepage from "./components/Homepage";
import Aboutpage from "./components/Aboutpage";

Vue.use(VueRouter);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes: [
    {
      path: "*",
      component: Homepage
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      component: Aboutpage
    }
  ]
});

new Vue({
  render: (h) => h(App),
  router
}).$mount("#app");
```

*App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
};
</script>

<style>
body {
  background: #292929;
}

#app {
  font-family: "Avenir", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
</style>
```

*Background.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="wrap">
    <transition
      name="page-shift"
      enter-active-class="animate__animated animate__slideInLeft animate__faster"
      leave-active-class="animate__animated animate__slideOutRight animate__faster"
    >
      <div v-if="showOverlay" class="overlay"></div>
    </transition>
    <navigation :menuOpen="menuOpen" @page-shift="pageShift" />
    <navbar @open-menu="menuOpen = !menuOpen" />
    <div>
      <div class="page d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
        <h1 class="text-light">{{ header }}</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Navbar from "./Navbar";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";

export default {
  name: "background",
  props: ["header"],
  data: function () {
    return {
      menuOpen: false,
      showOverlay: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Navbar,
    Navigation,
  },
  methods: {
    pageShift: function () {
      this.showOverlay = !this.showOverlay;
      const _this = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        _this.menuOpen = !_this.menuOpen;
      }, 500);
      setTimeout(function () {
        _this.showOverlay = !_this.showOverlay;
      }, 1000);
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;

  .overlay {
    width: inherit;
    height: inherit;
    background: #fff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
  }

  .page {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

*Navbar.vue

```
<template>
  <div class="navbar d-flex justify-content-end">
    <div
      @click="$emit('open-menu')"
      class="nav-link font-weight-bold mt-3 btn btn-primary"
    >
      Menu
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "navbar",
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 333;
  .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    cursor: pointer;
    border: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

*Navigation.vue

```
<template>
  <transition
    name="slide"
    enter-active-class="animate__animated animate__slideInLeft animate__faster"
    leave-active-class="animate__animated animate__slideOutLeft animate__faster"
  >
    <div v-if="menuOpen" class="navigation">
      <div
        class="container h-100 d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
      >
        <div class="text-center">
          <router-link to="/*" class="font-weight-bold text-light"
            ><h3 @click="$emit('page-shift')">HOME</h3></router-link
          >
          <router-link to="/about" class="font-weight-bold text-light"
            ><h3 @click="$emit('page-shift')">ABOUT</h3></router-link
          >
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </transition>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "navigation",
  props: ["menuOpen"],
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
.navigation {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #3ecc28;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 111;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;

  a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  span {
    cursor: pointer;
  }
}
</style>
```

*Homepage.vue

```
<template>
  <background :header="'HOME'" />
</template>

<script>
import Background from "./Background";

export default {
  name: "homepage",
  data: function () {
    return {
      menuOpen: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Background,
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

Aboutpage.vue

```
<template>
  <background :header="'ABOUT'" />
</template>

<script>
import Background from "./Background";

export default {
  name: "aboutpage",
  data: function () {
    return {
      menuOpen: false,
    };
  },
  components: {
    Background,
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
</style>
```

**The issue I have**
I discovered that if I stay in same router view, the animation will happen. If I go to another view, the page will re-render cause everything reload, so the animation will not happen at all. For example, in the sandbox, if you currently at home, and you click home, the animation will happen; but if you switch from home to about, the page will reload and the animation fails.

**What I've tried**
Well, I am new to vue. I think one solution is to prevent the page render when switch between different views. I do not know how to achieve that. I've tried use a transition tag around the router-view tag in the *App.vue*, but it doesn't achieve the ideal animation. I've also tried keep-alive, it doesn't work at all. Hope my explanation make sense and I am looking forward to your solutions! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're including the navigation inside your views, through `Background.vue`. Don't do that. Include it in `App.vue`.

When route changes, `<router-view />`'s content is populated with a brand new instance of that route's component (set in `routes` array in `router/index.ts` (or `.js`)). So, instead of:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>
```

... your `App.vue` should contain:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <navigation />
    <router-view />
  </div>
</template>
```

If there's any other part of your page which you don't want to re-render when the page is changed (some sidebar, maybe the footer), also include them inside `App.vue`. So, with footer and sidebar, it could look like:

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <header>
      <navigation />
    </header>
    <main>
      <sidebar />
      <router-view />
    </main>
    <footer />
  </div>
</template>
```

When route is changed, only `<router-view />` is re-rendered and animations set on your routes will be performed accordingly. Other layout elements placed directly in `App.vue` will not be re-rendered. Obviously, if you change their contents dynamically based on current route, those parts will update, but their base DOM element will remain the same.

Implicitly, you should remove `<navigation />` from your views, together with anything else you decide to place directly in `App.vue`.

Comment: Hi Tao, thank you so much! Your solution solved my problem. Just like what you've mentioned, the problem is because I included the animation components inside the `router-view`, so it re-render every time. I just move it out from the `router-view`, and it now works great!

Comment: @Liang, here's an attempt to re-organize what you had: https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-page-shift-anime-forked-bxw0c?file=/src/App.vue. Problem is I don't really know how it was supposed to behave, so... Anyway, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for making this. It's really helpful! BTW, the animation looks really cool to me ;)